# Crash when unwrapping option even though it isn't nil

Tags: ios, swift

Hey I have a custom init method in my custom UIView like so:

```
init(frame: CGRect, otherUser: MyUser?) {

        self.otherUser = otherUser
        super.init(frame: frame)
        if self.otherUser != nil {
            print("THE USER IS NOT NIL")
            nameLabel.text = self.otherUser!.username ?? ""
            cityLabel.text = self.otherUser!.cityName ?? ""
            ratingView.rating = self.otherUser!.rating ?? 0

        }

    }
```

I am passing a MyUser object as a parameter. At the time I init this object shouldn't be nil and it even passes the nil check and prints "THE USER IS NOT NIL". However when I force unwrap it the app crashes. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: `nameLabel` `cityLabel` or `ratingView` may be nil

Answer (score 1):

You should call super first, don't access `self` until that's done. You can also shorten your code and reduce function calls with a little change to the logical check:

```
init(frame: CGRect, otherUser: MyUser?) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    if let otherUser = otherUser {
        print("THE USER IS NOT NIL")
        self.otherUser = otherUser
        nameLabel.text = otherUser.username ?? ""
        cityLabel.text = otherUser.cityName ?? ""
        ratingView.rating = otherUser.rating ?? 0
    }
}
```

There's a good chance that the user is not the problem as there is no code to create the labels and anything coming from a NIB won't be ready yet. This `init` method also wouldn't be called if you were loading from a NIB.

So you most likely really need to look at the labels and other view configuration and / or the way that you instantiate this view. Probably you want to create a setter function (or a `didSet` on the property) to configure these details.